# Como simular efeito de click em p:commandLink?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Nos botões no primefaces há uma efeito, o usuário vê ele sendo clicado (afundar), o mesmo não ocorre quando clico em commandLink:

```
 <p:commandLink  id="logs" immediate="true" value="Event" onclick="showModalPopUp();" 
        style="color: #333333 !important; font-weight: bold;">
                    </p:commandLink>
```

Como posso simular esse efeito ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu usei:

```
<p:effect type="clip" event="click" />
```

Um exemplo aqui:

```
<h3 style="margin-top:0">Catalog</h3>
<h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5">
    <p:panel id="blind" header="Blind">
        <h:outputText value="click" />
        <p:effect type="blind" event="click">
            <f:param name="direction" value="'horizontal'" />
        </p:effect>
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel id="clip" header="Clip">
        <h:outputText value="click" />
        <p:effect type="clip" event="click" />
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel id="drop" header="Drop">
        <h:outputText value="click" />
        <p:effect type="drop" event="click" />
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel id="explode" header="Explode">
        <h:outputText value="click" />
        <p:effect type="explode" event="click" />
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel id="fold" header="Fold">
        <h:outputText value="doubleclick" />
        <p:effect type="fold" event="dblclick" />
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel id="puff" header="Puff">
        <h:outputText value="doubleclick" />
        <p:effect type="puff" event="dblclick" />
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel id="slide" header="Slide">
        <h:outputText value="doubleclick" />
        <p:effect type="slide" event="dblclick" />
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel id="scale" header="Scale">
        <h:outputText value="doubleclick" />
        <p:effect type="scale" event="dblclick">
            <f:param name="percent" value="90" />
        </p:effect>
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel id="bounce" header="Bounce">
        <h:outputText value="click" />
        <p:effect type="bounce" event="click" />
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel id="pulsate" header="Pulsate">
        <h:outputText value="click" />
        <p:effect type="pulsate" event="click" />
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel id="shake" header="Shake">
        <h:outputText value="click" />
        <p:effect type="shake" event="click" />
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel id="size" header="Size">
        <h:outputText value="click" />
        <p:effect type="size" event="click">
            <f:param name="to" value="{width: 200,height: 60}" />
        </p:effect>
    </p:panel>
</h:panelGrid>

<h3>Target</h3>
<p:commandButton type="button" value="Show" style="display:block" icon="ui-icon-image">
    <p:effect type="puff" event="click" for="img">
        <f:param name="mode" value="'show'" />
    </p:effect>
</p:commandButton>
<p:graphicImage id="img" name="demo/images/nature/nature1.jpg" style="display:none"/>

<h:form>
    <h3>On Load</h3>
    <p:messages id="messages" closable="true">
        <p:effect type="pulsate" event="load" delay="500" />
    </p:messages>

    <p:panel id="panel" header="Message Effects" toggleable="true">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
            <p:outputLabel for="text" value="Type:" />
            <p:inputText id="text" value="#{effectView.text}" required="true" />

            <h:outputText />
            <p:commandButton id="submit" value="Echo" actionListener="#{effectView.echo}" update="messages"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</h:form
```

>

```
package org.primefaces.showcase.view.misc;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
public class EffectView {

    private String text;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void echo() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("You said:'" + text + "'"));
    }
}
```

Aqui a fonte:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/effect.xhtml